# Why i got wrong in FirebaseAuth?

Tags: android

[FirebaseAuth shows wrong , please anybody help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P99BC.png)

Comment: no images of code please

Comment: please read this :- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it's help you get more answer !

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported the `FirebaseAuth` class.

Paste this into the top of `RegistrationActivity.java`.

`import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;`